# Pandas groupby group visualization by dividing between groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, visualization

I am facing a very annoying problem. I have a dataset where I have the sales amounts for different regions and years.

I would like to visualize the yearly aggregated sales amounts based on different regions.

Below is my groupby code:

```
groups = df.groupby(["Region", "Year"])["Sales"].sum()
groups.plot.bar(color="blue")
plt.show()
```

And the output I get looks like this:
[image]

I have two questions:
1. How could I somehow separate the region and year bars from each other as this way my chart looks really confusing? A separator line or actually a highlighter would also work, or even a bigger gap would be a good solution to me.
(Please see below, what I mean:)
[image]
or
[image]

I have no clue at all, how to solve this problem.

Question no 2. How could I have this image sorted by the regions with most sales, followed by the second most sales yearly, and so on? Kind of sorting in a descending order based on regions.

I tried the code below:

```
groups = df.groupby(["Region", "Year"])["Sales"].sum()
groups2=groups.sort_values(axis=[0][1],ascending=False)
groups.plot.bar(color="blue")
plt.show()
```

But I get a list index out of range error. Using axis=[0] does not solve the problem.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: [seaborn barplots](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) accept a second variable `hue` that allows this sort of grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following ChrisD's advice you can obtain a working result with [seaborn's `catplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) to display your bars into different facets by region.

```
sns.catplot(x='Year', y='Sales', col='Region', data=groups, kind='bar')
```

You may have to format the aspect ratios for your display purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I get a "Could not interpret" Year" error. What am I doing wrong? :(
Thank you!

Comment: It may be an issue of the data table shape or format. Have you tried reseting the index in your groupby with reset_index()?

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin! No, I didnt reset the index. So now I reset it and works like a charm! :) Thank you so much!
Is there any way to sort all these chart in descending order? I mean that the region which has the most sales should be put first and all the others follow in a descending order?
Thank you again for your tremendous help!

Comment: You can typically order the data visualized using catplot's order parameters like col_order (maybe row_order, hue_order, or order depending on your taste). Have you tried that out?

Comment: I know I should be looking arounc col_order but I am not sure what should I add as parameter... I could not figure it out from the information on catplot method unfortunately. :(